# count objects of a certain type in a collection and use this as a string in a textbox

Tags: c#

I want to fill a textbox with the count+1 of a kind of figure in a collection.
The collection is a Generic List of Figure, figure is an instance of a certain type of Figure.

The following works:

```
txtName.Text = figures.OfType<Square>().Count().ToString();
```

but the following doen't

```
txtName.Text = figures.OfType<figure.GetType()>().Count().ToString();
```

I get the error "operator '>' can not be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'".
What do i have to do to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic type parameters need to be specified at compile-time, but `GetType()` is a function called at run time, so this simply won't work. The error message indicates that the compiler is trying to interpret your code as `figures.OfType < figure.GetType() ...` which doesn't make much sense.

You can do this:

```
// Count figures whose type is exactly equal to the type of figure
txtName.Text = figures.Count(x => figure.GetType() == x.GetType()).ToString();

// Count figures whose type is equal to or a subtype of the type of figure
txtName.Text = figures.Count(x => figure.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x.GetType())).ToString();
```

Comment: works, thanks but why did you change your answer, the first worked also and was simpler, still one problem, i want to add the typename of the figure also but i get the assemblyname with it figure.GetType().ToString() gives me exercise1.Form1+Circle1

Comment: @peter I've updated my answer to provide clarification on both options. To get just the simple class name use `figure.GetType().Name`